# How do I filter a Django Queryset by removing results in which another model has a ForeignKey relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

With the following models.py ...

```
from django.db import models

class Notebook(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    
class Entry(models.Model):
    notebook = models.ForeignKey(Notebook, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How would I write a filter to only return Notebook that have no Entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.filter(…)` the `Notebook`s with:

```
Notebook.objects.filter(entry=None)
```

This works because Django makes a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and thus we only retain the records for which the `entry` primary key is `NULL`/`None`.